# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable python

Tags: python, opencv

```
def crop (img_path):
    img = cv.imread(img_path)
    img_crop = img[60:140,0:320,:]
    for a in labels:
        cv.imwrite(path_save+a, img_crop)
```

When I run this code, it reveals that:

> `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Looks like `cv.imread` returns returns a `None` instead of the image. Can you verify this by printing `img` or `type(img)` ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this? Please include all the relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is the line which is attempting to subscript the variable `img_crop`:

`img_crop = img[60:140,0:320,:]`

So at some point in the loop, `cv.imread(img_path)` is returning None. A simple boolean `if` statement would skip the error:

```
def crop (img_path):
    img = cv.imread(img_path)
    if img:
        img_crop = img[60:140,0:320,:]
        for a in labels:
            cv.imwrite(path_save+a, img_crop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should doublecheck that the image you open actually exists. From the code that you shared with us, it seems that `cv.imread(img_path)` returns None and then the error is thrown in the next line when you try to access the `None` contents by index.

Thus my suggestion is to update the code as follows:

```
def crop (img_path):
    img = cv.imread(img_path)
    if img is None:
        # todo handle bad/nonexisting img case
        pass
    img_crop = img[60:140,0:320,:]
    for a in labels:
        cv.imwrite(path_save+a, img_crop)
```

or for you to make sure that the path you pass here is always correct in the code that is calling this function.